# Annotation cannot show all labels in geom-signif

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am preparing a bar plot using ggplot2, ggsignif, and facet_wrap. I have got some error in my script, which is "Warning message:
Ignoring unknown aesthetics: xmin, xmax, annotations, y_position",and "*** annotation".
The followings are my raw data and my script.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/179vDFGtEheGV8S74M4R25ZsPgQLBVOVt/view?usp=sharing

```
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsignif)
Raw <- read_excel("Raw data.xls", 
                  col_types = c("numeric", "numeric", "numeric", 
                                "numeric"))
Raw$Sacrifice<-factor(Raw$Sacrifice,levels = c(1,2,3),
                      labels = c("First week","Second week","Third week"))
Raw$Treatment_gr<-factor(Raw$Treatment_gr,levels = c(1,2),
                         labels = c("Treatment_A","Treatment_B"))
Raw$Treatment_receive<-factor(Raw$Treatment_receive,levels = c(1,2,3),
                              labels = c("Intact nerve","Sensory cut","Autonomic cut"))
annotation_df <- data.frame(Treatment_gr=c(rep("Treatment_A",5), rep("Treatment_B",4)),
                            Treatment_receive=c(rep("Intact nerve",3),rep("Sensory cut",2),rep("Intact nerve",2),rep("Autonomic cut",2)),
                            start=c(0.9,1.9,0.9,1.1,2.1,0.9,0.9,1.1,2.1),
                            end=c(1.9,2.9,2.9,3.1,3.1,1.9,2.9,3.1,3.1),
                            y=c(17,17,19,23,21,17,19,21,23),
                            label=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"))
ggplot(Raw,aes(Sacrifice,Leukocyte_count,fill=Treatment_receive),stat="identity")+
  stat_summary(fun=mean,
               geom = "bar",
               width=0.5,
               position = "dodge")+
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se,
               geom = "errorbar",
               fun.args = list(mult = 1),
               position = position_dodge(0.5),
               width=0.2)+
  labs(x="Duration of Observation (week)",
       y="Number of Leukocyte",
       fill ="Treatment Receive")+
  geom_signif(data = annotation_df,
              aes(xmin=start,xmax=end,annotations=label,y_position=y),
              tip_length = 0.01, manual = TRUE, inherit.aes=FALSE)+
  facet_wrap(~ Treatment_gr, nrow = 1)+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[A result from the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsyVq.jpg)

However, I would like to replace the number in the label with asterisks.
The result of annotation in the plot is different. The asterisks are not placed like in the previous one.

[A result after I replaced the numbers with asterisks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNBOj.jpg)

How can I make the script to annotate all asterisks?

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for posting a reproducible case. I found the following page describing the same issue: https://github.com/const-ae/ggsignif/issues/63

Therefore I suggest you the following workaround: (I tested it myself, it should work.)

1. Adding group column: each row (i.e., comparison) is considered as a different group
2. Specifying the group in aes()

```
annotation_df$group <- 1:nrow(annotation_df)


geom_signif(data = annotation_df,
                 aes(xmin=start,xmax=end,annotations="***",y_position=y, group=group),
                 tip_length = 0.01, manual = TRUE, inherit.aes=FALSE)
```